# Proving that $T(X)$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$

Tags: statistics

I have that $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$ is a rv consisting of $n$ iid exponential rv's where $\theta$ is the parameter (and thus mean $1\over \theta$) .

I have to prove that $T(X)=\sum^n_{i=1}X_i$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ using the theorem in my textbook which states that if $\frac{f_{\theta}(x)}{f^T_{\theta}(T(x))}$ is constant in $\theta$ then $T(X)$ is a sufficient statistic for ${\theta}$.

So what I've done is:

First I calculated $f_{\theta}(x)= \theta^n e^{-\theta\sum^n_{i=1}X_i}$ since $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ are iid.

Then I calculated $f_{\theta}^T(T(x))= \frac{{\sum^n_{i=1}X_i}^{n-1}e^{\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}}{\theta}}}{\theta^n(n-1)!}$ since $T(X)\sim gamma(n,\theta)$

So now using the theorem with the ratio I get stuck because the $\theta$'s don't cancel out:

$$\frac{f_{\theta}(x)}{f^T_{\theta}(T(x))}=\frac{\theta^n e^{-\theta\sum^n_{i=1}X_i}}{\frac{{\sum^n_{i=1}X_i}^{n-1}e^{\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}}{\theta}}}{\theta^n(n-1)!}}$$ $$=$$
$$\frac{\theta^{2n} (n-1)!e^{\frac{1-\theta^2}{\theta}\sum^n_{i=1}x_i}}{{\sum^n_{i=1}}^{n-1}}$$

So by my calculation(probably which are wrong), $\theta$ is not cancelling out. Any mistakes that I have made that you could possibly see? Any help would be appreciated!

Here's the theorem in my textbook:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your expression for the exponential distribution uses $\theta$ as a rate while your expression for the gamma distribution uses $\theta$ as a scale.  They need to be consistent so that the $\theta^n$ terms cancel each other out rather than combining to $\theta^{2n}$

Comment: but anyway it's would not cancel out

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/445596/119261. Please avoid cross-posting in general.

Comment: Is there a community guideline which I have violated? If so, sorry, will avoid

Comment: @ThePoorJew https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9337/is-cross-posted-forbidden-discouraged-on-stack-exchange-sites-if-so-why, https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2131/cross-posting-on-math-and-cv,

Comment: @StubbornAtom ok i get it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression for the exponential distribution uses θ as a rate while your expression for the gamma distribution uses θ as a scale. They need to be consistent.  So

- You found $f_{\theta}(x)= \theta^n e^{-\theta\sum\limits^n_{i=1}x_i}$ which is $\theta^n e^{-\theta T(x)}$ since $T(x) = \sum\limits^n_{i=1}x_i$
- You should have found $f_{\theta}^T(T(x))= \theta^n \frac{T(x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} e^{-\theta T(x)}$
- That makes $\dfrac{f_{\theta}(x)}{f^T_{\theta}(T(x))} = \dfrac{(n-1)!}{T(x)^{n-1}}$ which does not depend on $\theta$ or the individual $x_i$ except through $T(x)$

Comment: I don't understand how you found the expression for $f^T_{\theta}(T(X))$ . By this(https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27908/sum-of-exponential-random-variables-follows-gamma-confused-by-the-parameters) link, second answer, the scale of the gamma distributed $T(X)$ is $\theta$ hence $T(X) \sim \Gamma(n, \theta)$ and then by the screenshot on my question, the gamma variable with scale $\theta$ is distributed accordingly to the picture, am i wrong?

Comment: If you could clarify how you found $f^T_{\theta}(T(X))$ , then I think i would understand

Comment: Try [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) where the shape is $\alpha$ (your $n$) and the rate (not scale) is $\beta$ (your $\theta$).  If $E[X_i]=\frac1\theta$ then $E[T(X)]=\frac n \theta$ not $n \theta$

Answer (score 0):

The condition "$\frac{f_{\theta}(x)}{f^T_{\theta}(T(x))}$ is constant in $\theta$" can be rephrased as:

Joint probability density function of $X_i$ can be written in the form:

$$f(X_i;\theta) = g(T(X_i);\theta) \,\, h(X_i)$$

Note that first term doesn't depend on individual $X_i$'s only on the statistic, while second term is not dependent on $\theta$ (think of it as $X$ interacting with $\theta$ only through $T$).

For iid exponentials it turns out that $h(X_i)$ is just a constant so it's even simpler. Namely:

$$ f(X_i;\theta) = \theta^n \exp(-\theta T(X_i)) \times 1$$

Which gives you explicit decomposition.

Comment: that's the Fisher-Neymann factorisastion theorem? That was my second way to prove it on this exercise which I did, but I would like to prove it with the ratio theorem

Comment: As per wikipedia: A statistic t = T(X) is sufficient for underlying parameter θ precisely if the conditional probability distribution of the data X, given the statistic t = T(X), does not depend on the parameter θ.
Ratio of densities is not the same as conditional pdf. It's somewhat murky for me then what $f_\theta^{T}(T(x))$ is if not what I denoted as $g$.

Comment: it is the pdf of $T(X)=\sum^n_{i=1}X_i \sim \Gamma(n,\theta)$

Comment: I understand what you've computed. I'm not sure if it's relevant to showing $T$ is sufficient. To verify that $X_i | T$ is indep. on $\theta$ one doesn't need to know distribution of $T$.